# PHP - Wordpress - include in ajax action is commenting php declarations

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm working with wordpress and i want to load a template in an ajax action and render it to the current loaded page.
**The problem is that all PHP declarations are being commented..**

heres the code

```
       if ( isset($_GET['block_id']) && $this->blocks[$_GET['block_id']]) {
            ob_start();
            include($this->blocks[$_GET['block_id']]['admin_template']);
            echo ob_get_clean();
        }
        die();
```

it returns something like

```
       <label><!-- ?php _e('Products count', 'wc_blocks'); ? --></label>
```

I even tried to remove the ob_start() and ob_get_clean() but it keeps commeting all php declarations.

```
        if ( isset($_GET['block_id']) && $this->blocks[$_GET['block_id']]) {

            include($this->blocks[$_GET['block_id']]['admin_template']);

        }
        die();
```

Any suggestions?
Happy programming!